# Vários comandos de update separados por ";" (ponto e virgula) no SQLite!

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

**Problema**

Estou tentando aplicar o seguinte script/comando em um versão de meu banco de dados SQLite:

```
UPDATE UF
   SET DATE_CREATE = DATE_UPDATE;

UPDATE CIDADE
   SET DATE_CREATE = DATE_UPDATE;

UPDATE CLIENTE
   SET DATE_CREATE = DATE_UPDATE;
```

Mas só aplica na tabela `CLIENTE`, e demais o campo `DATE_CREATE` continua `NULL`.

Isso acontece tando ao aplicar no Android com o [`db.execSQL(script)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) quanto no  [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/) em minha maquina local.

No SQLiteStudio é apresentada a seguinte mensagem no console:

```
[15:14:14] Query finished in 0.055 second(s). Rows affected: 531
```

Onde os 531 rows são os 531 registros da tabela de `CLIENTE` onde estou testando os scripts. A tabela de `CIDADE` tem 5603 registros e de `UF` tem 27 registros.

**Pergunta**

Alguém sabe me dizer se o SQLite tem alguma restrição ao aplicar vários comandos em um mesmo script? Ou há alguma falha em meu script?

Comment: Essa resposta (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12742226/2236741) me fez pensar numa sugestão: faça cada UPDATE numa linha apenas e veja se funciona.

Comment: O fato da mensagem do SQLiteStudio mostrar apenas os 531 registros afetados não é um problema, já que ela deve se referir sempre a última sentença executada. Estranho é o update não ter sido aplicado nas tabelas UF e CIDADE. Outra sugestão, coloque o ; numa linha separada, como mostrado aqui (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12742282).

Comment: Qual a versão do seu SQLite?

Comment: @David, 3.8.6 no Android e 3.8.10 no SQLiteStudio!

Comment: @cantoni, tentei o que você sugeriu de quebrar a linha para por o ";" (ponto e virgula), mesmo assim continua o mesmo comportamento!

Comment: E cada update numa linha?

Comment: @cantoni, é como está na pergunta, mas até onde sei não importaria se é na mesma linha ou não, já que o ";" (ponto e virgula) era para ser o separador entre um comando e o outro. Intrigante esse comportamento! =(

Comment: Sim. Também acho o mesmo. Eu achei tão estranho que propus essas duas tentativas.

Comment: Realmente @ramaral, as respostas da duplicata respondem a pergunta, eu até já tinha implementado dessa forma, executando cada comando em um `execSQL()`, mas não tinha visto na documentação que isso era uma limitação! E o SQLiteStudio deve utilizar um `execSQL` também com a mesma limitação para aplicar os scripts por isso o problema acontece nele também! Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.